# Is there a C function to convert a string with a number in base X to a string in base Y?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, radix

I am aware that `strtol(hexstring, NULL, 16)` will convert my string `hexstring`, which is hexadecimal, to a decimal. Likewise this would be the case in binary in `strtol(binstring, NULL, 2)`. Is there a function that will do this in general? From one base to the next? If not, can someone propose the most line-efficient way?

Comment: `int`s aren't in "decimal" on the machine; they're in binary, but usually printed in decimal. `itoa` can convert an integer to a string with arbitrary base.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will look into this!

Comment: However, `itoa` is not a standard C function. BTW, you could code one quite easily.

Comment: Unless you need bases outside the range 2-36 (or non-standard encodings for bases), the `strtol()` family of functions serves to convert from string to internal (binary, non-string) format.  You then need a separate function to convert from the internal format to a string format in an arbitrary base.  Standard C doesn't provide such a function — you have to look elsewhere.

Comment: You can use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916666/recursive-function-to-convert-between-number-bases-fails-at-certain-numbers. You will understand.

Comment: @Shiv: You've linked to a curious (interesting) question — it certainly isn't a general answer to this one, though the subject matter is related.

Comment: What do you mean by 'line-efficient', Jerry?  Number of lines of code in the calling code base, or number of lines of code in the function doing the conversion?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: both, what you proposed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP all ready knows how to convert a string `s` representing `base` digits into an integer.  Sample usage:

```
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
unsigned long y = strtoul(s, &endptr, base);
if (endptr == s) No_conversion();
if (errno) Handle_Overflow();
if (*endptr) Handle_TrailingText();
```

An easy away to convert an unsigned integer uses a *compound literal* for memory allocation.

[How to use compound literals to `fprintf()` multiple formatted numbers with arbitrary bases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34292060/2410359)

If you need other methods, search on [`0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%5d%20%200123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ).

Answer (score 3):

This is one proposition of a **C99** base_convert :

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *base_convert(const char * str, const int base_in, const int base_out) {
    static const char *alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    size_t a, b, c = 1, d;
    char *s = malloc(c + 1);
    strcpy(s, "0");
    for (; *str; ++str) {
        for (a = (char*)memchr(alphabet, *str, base_out) - alphabet, b = c; b;) {
            d = ((char *) memchr(alphabet, s[--b], base_out) - alphabet) * base_in + a;
            s[b] = alphabet[d % base_out];
            a = d / base_out;
        }
        for (; a; s = realloc(s, ++c + 1), memmove(s + 1, s, c), *s = alphabet[a % base_out], a /= base_out);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Example usage :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char a[] = "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                     "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                     "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                     "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    char *b = base_convert(a, 2, 10);
    puts(b);
    free(b);
}
```

It's [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71890649/18765627), example output :

```c
13479973333575319897333507543509815336818572211270286240551805124608
```